# How come when I try to download the Android Support Package Revision 10, it keeps saying file not found?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The only way I can get eclipse to work for writing android apps is by installing the Android Support Package(revision 8, 9, or 10) from the android SDK. I click on the link to download it and it then tells me this: SDK Manager] File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\support_r10.zip (Access is denied). I do not know why this is happening and I can't even create a project until I fix this problem. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Bug : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859

Answer (score 5):

This is how I fixed the problem

Steps:

1.) Run your Android SDK Manager

2) Find Extras > support Library and delete that particular Library

[image]

3) Now  Relaunch Android SDK MAnager

4) Download the   Extras > support Library present

Try making a new project now

Answer (score 1):

Please run you SDK Manager as an administrator. Right click on it and choose "Run as administrator" It should install it then.

Comment: Of course, this is done on the SDK Manager.exe itself, no way to do it in Eclipse :). Alternatively you could start Eclipse as Administrator and then when you start the SDK Manager from within, it will have admin rights, too.