# can't install support library

Tags: android, sdk

I am trying to start developing android apps. I think I need to install support library-revision 10 first.However I get error...

I tried to install it by using sdk manager. It gives an error like this:

> Downloading Android Support Library, revision 10
>
> > File not found: C:\Program Files
> >     (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\support_r10.zip (access is denied)
>
> Done. Nothing was installed.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230735/how-come-when-i-try-to-download-the-android-support-package-revision-10-it-keep/12230898#12230898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running whichever program you are using to install as an administrator, 
run your SDK Manager as an administrator. Right click on it and choose "Run as administrator" It should install it then.(Right Click -> Run As Administrator).

Comment: You can run SDK manager outside of eclipse, go to android-sdk\platform-tools. from there you´l also be able to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when SDK Manager tries to modify the file that is being used by eclipse. Try this Exit eclipse(you may need to restart your system aslo) - go to your android sdk folder - open SDK manager directly from there(not from eclipse)- now update the libraries.